# Problems with eye shading

Tags: blender, shading

I am trying to get the transparent part of the eye to reflect the iris, but it is completely transparent no matter what I do

I also cant seem to get the bump node to work for some reason.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not fill your post with repeated or nonsense content as a way to work around the quality filter. If the system prompts you to add additional explanation to your post, then do so. Don't attempt to bypass the warning. This is considered an abuse of the system, and may lead to your post being summarily removed and/or your account being sanctioned.  Take the [tour], read up on [ask] and then [edit] your post with more details.